# Lutra input app data transfer with PC

Tags: qgis, data-transfer, mergin-maps

This question was similarly asked and answered (and closed) last year so I am looking for clarification. Paraphrasing, the response was that without Mergin, it would be difficult to share data with QGIS on a computer. If difficult, then it is possible? Has anyone come up with the process?

(I’m considering getting an iPhone but won’t because QField won’t run on iOS.)

Comment: An iOS version is in the making via testflight https://qfield.org/docs/install/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Transferring data through USB cable between Input app and PC is only one way in iOS: from iPhone/iPad to PC.

Note that Mergin is not only used for data transfer, but also allows collaborative mode, so you do not need to manually patch your survey layer with edits from multiple sources. Mergin is free and open source and you can run your own instance for data transfer between your QGIS and iOS:
https://github.com/lutraconsulting/mergin